# MongoSpark save duplicated key error E11000

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark

I have a Spark application that writes RDD data to MongoDB and I'm getting a *MongoBulkWriteException*. Formerly, I was using the *bulkWrite()* method from MongoDB standard driver, **but I've started using the *write()* method from the MongoSpark driver**.

Before anything else, I'm using **Apache Spark 1.6.0** and **MongoDB 3.2.11**.

This the exception trace:

```
com.mongodb.MongoBulkWriteException: Bulk write operation error on server
 10.1.101.146:27017. Write errors: [BulkWriteError{index=0, code=11000, 
message='E11000 duplicate key error collection: collection-test 
index: _id_ dup key: { : "636253651-2017-03-07" }', details={ }}]
```

The code that produces it is:

```
JavaRDD<Document> rddInsertRecords = rddGrouped.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, BasicRecord>, Document>() {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public Document call(Tuple2<String, BasicRecord> tuple2) throws Exception {
          Document json = tuple2._2.toBSONDocument();
          return json;
      }
});
MongoSpark.save(rddInsertRecords, WriteConfig.create(sc.getConf()));
```

I have an alternative solution using my old code, but I want to write using MongoSpark.

I've seen this issue in MongoDB's JIRA (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14322), but I'm not sure on how can I bypass the problem.

**UPDATE**: I forgot to mention that the failure does not happen the first time (i.e. No data on mongodb, the collection is empty). It fails when running the job for a second time. Technically the driver should do an upsert, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spark Connector does not know how to upsert `RDD<T>` where `T` can be any type - how can it get the id value?

However, Datasets/DataFrames have schema information with them indicating which field is the `_id` field and can automatically be used for upserts.  This was done in [SPARK-66](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SPARK-66).  Another benefit of Datasets/DataFrames is they are more efficient and should give a performance boost to your Spark jobs.

If you have to use RDD's then you can programatically access the MongoDB collection and create an upsert operation via the `MongoConnector` class.

Comment: Roger that. I can't by the moment switch RDDs to Datasets so I think I'll use the MongoConnector approach. Thanks for the clarification.